# PhpStorm Remote FTP "no files found"

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am new to PhpStorm and try to connect the project to my existing folders and files on my FTP server. I configured the deployment settings first in the settings menu and for testing via "create project from existing files" in another project. Both ways, I can connect to my FTP server and can browse through the server folders.

But not all of the files are shown in PhpStorm. E.g. I can find the file `index.php` but not `2.bs-test.template.php` in the developer folder (which exists on FileZilla but not for PhpStorm). Therefore, some folders are completely "empty" for PhpStorm and I cannot download and edit these files...

When I try to download the error "No files or folders found to process" occurs.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe check file/folder permissions on the target machine

Comment: I tried setting these "invisible" files to 777 but still not shown in phpStorm. But all the "empty" folders are shown...

Comment: @Jonas Deployment logs from IDE and FileZilla will be required for such kind of issues (to see FTP listing details and compare them). I suggest submitting a Support Ticket with JetBrains Support Team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 (or the same via `Help | Contact Support...` from within PhpStorm) where you can privately submit any required info as requested. P.S. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: In my case, some folders had suffixes like `.../foldername [2]/...`.

PhpStorm is not able to read files in these folders with special suffixes like  `[2]`. After I removed the suffixes the files appeared - without any changes in remote settings.